# Windows Server 2016 shows only partially in English

Tags: windows-server-2016, localization, language-packs

I've configued English as the default language on the server, however, I still get modules in the Server Manager in Dutch (this is how my VPS was initially setup by my hosting provider) and also I receive ASP.NET error notifications on the frontend in Dutch. This makes debugging extremely complex since error notification fixes are always best found in English when searching on Google. How can I convert my server fully to the English language, so all Windows/IIS modules and ASP.NET error notifications?

Some screenshots to illustrate what I already tried (and yes I rebooted the server a bunch of times already):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the Dutch language completely from the server? A reboot might be required as well.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick...since you were the first, please make this the answer so I can reward you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered such behavior in the past.

From my experience, completely removing the Dutch language from the server and then rebooting the server should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the display language for the server/VPS.

Go to the Control panel >> Clock, Language, and Region, if you are using the Classic view. Advance Settings in the left panel.

Finally set the "Override for Windows display language" to the language you want to use and optionally click the link under the dropdown to also use this language at the welcome screen and for new user accounts.

Click Save to apply the language change and log off and re-logon to immediately see the result.

I hope it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove Dutch from the language list and reboot the server.

If you are going to use English then why not make it the only language installed?

After you do that you shouldn’t have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to go to *Control Panel* > *Region* > *Administrative* (Tab) > *Change system locale...* and switch to the language you want.

This worked for me in Windows Server Manager.